# How can I assign values to a opencv matrix Mat?

Tags: opencv, mat

For example, I have a 2by3 matrix [1,0,5;1,0,-5], and a Mat trans_mat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1).

How can I assign those values to the trans_mat matrix?

Comment: trans_mat.at<float>(y,x) = xxx;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mat trans_mat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1);
trans_mat = (Mat_<float>(2, 3) << 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, -5);
```